# How to bring a Matrix to an advanced Coefficient matrix in row form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I just found this website on the Internet and you are really my last chance to help me with one task.
For $ a \in \mathbb{R}$, let the following linear equation system be given:
$$
\begin{array}{rcrcrcc}
(a+1)x_{1} & + & (-a^2+6a-9)x_{2} & + & (a-2)x_{3} & = & 1\\
(a+1)(a-3)x_{1} & + & (a^2-6a+9)x_{2} & + & 3x_{3} & = & a-3\\
(a+1)x_{1} & + & (-a^2+6a-9)x_{2} & + & (a+1)x_{3} & = & 1\\
\end{array}
$$
Now I should bring that in the Matrix form $\mathbf{A}x=b$, which isn't a problem.
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 
(a+1) & (-a^2+6a-9) & (a-2) \\
(a+1)(a-3) & (a^2-6a+9) &  3 \\
(a+1) & (-a^2+6a-9) & (a+1)
\end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix} 
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
a-3 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But now I should bring it to the advanced Coefficient matrix in row form.
Can someone explain to me how to do it? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you, I saw that, i just need a hint how to bring it to the coefficient matrix

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where Cramer's Rule applies quite nicely.

First, note that
$$
\det(A)
= 3 \, {\left(a + 1\right)} {\left(a - 2\right)} {\left(a - 3\right)}^{2}
$$
So, $A$ is invertible as long as $a\notin\{-1, 2, 3\}$.

Next, define $A_i$ as the matrix obtained by replacing the $i$th column of $A$ with the vector $\vec{b}=\left\langle1,\,a - 3,\,1\right\rangle$. This gives
$$
\begin{align*}
\det(A_1) &= 3 \, {\left(a - 2\right)} {\left(a - 3\right)}^{2} &
\det(A_2) &= 0 &
\det(A_3) &= 0
\end{align*}
$$
By Cramer's Rule, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
x_1 &= \frac{\det(A_1)}{\det(A)} = \frac{1}{a + 1} &
x_2 &= \frac{\det(A_2)}{\det(A)} = 0 &
x_3 &= \frac{\det(A_3)}{\det(A)} = 0 
\end{align*}
$$
Of course, we should also account for what happens if $a\in\{-1, 2, 3\}$.

For $a=-1$, we can row-reduce the system to obtain
$$
\operatorname{rref}\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
0 & -16 & -3 & 1 \\
0 & 16 & 3 & -4 \\
0 & -16 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
For $a=2$, we have
$$
\operatorname{rref}\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
3 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
-3 & 1 & 3 & -1 \\
3 & -1 & 3 & 1
\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
For $a=3$, we have
$$
\operatorname{rref}\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
4 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 4 & 1
\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$

Answer (score 0):

### Problem statement

Solve the linear system $\mathbf{A}x=b$:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{crc}
 a+1 & -(a-3)^2 & a-2 \\
 (a-3) (a+1) & (a-3)^2 & 3 \\
 a+1 & -(a-3)^2 & a+1 
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\x_{3}
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\ a-3 \\ 1
\end{array}\right].
$$

### Gaussian Elimination

Two reduction steps are used resulting in
$$
\mathbf{E}_{2}\mathbf{E}_{1}\mathbf{A}x=\mathbf{E}_{2}\mathbf{E}_{1}b
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{E}_{1} =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{a+1} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{a+1} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{a+1} \\
\end{array}
\right], \qquad
\mathbf{E}_{2} =
\left[
\begin{array}{rcc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & \frac{1}{a-3} & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right].
$$

### Solution via back substitution

The final linear system is
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -\frac{(a-3)^2}{a+1} &
   \frac{a-2}{a+1} \\
 0 & \frac{a^2-5 a+6}{a+1} &
   \frac{a^2-5 a+3}{-a^2+2 a+3} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{a+1} \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\x_{3}
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{a+1} \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}\right].
$$
Solution vis back substitution produces
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ x_{3}
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{a+1} \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}\right],
\qquad a\ne1.
$$